# Principal Component Analysis and Time Series

Tags: time-series, pca, factor-analysis, categorical-encoding

I'm a PhD student with a very superficial knowledge of statistics and econometrics. I am trying to build an index representing the intensity of rental regulation in my country from 1915 to the present. This index should "summarize" different detailed (numerical) indicators, each representing a very specific feature of the regulation (most of them will be dummies).

I have read something about weighted indices, built through a Principal Component Analysis, but:
- I wasn't able to understand if this method can be used with time series; the papers I read only used it with cross-sectional datasets. 
- Because of my very lacking knowledge of statistics, I'm not even sure this method would lead me to the index I am trying to build!

Is there anyone who could help me? I appreciate every suggestion, warning or advice for further readings. If you need more info about the data and research question,just ask :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you have $n$ years of data for $k$ measures of regulation? You can easily apply PCA to transform that into $n$ years of data for $l < k$ orthogonal indices (eg. $l = 1$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please suggest me something to read about that, specific to weighted indices, PCA and time series? I'm only finding papers on comparative, cross-countries analyses (which apply PCA on cross-sectional data) and, being a total beginner, I could really use an example in the literature..Thanks again!